# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on 1 GB RAM virtual?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

i have an ASP.NET application (website, catalog-like). No high load expected (not more than 50 concurrent users, lets say, and 95% just read - it is a website), but it has some specific needs, so i cant host it on shared hosting, and going for hosted virtual server. Configuration is like this - 2 GHz core (agregated 1:5), 1024 dedicated RAM, 30GB disk space. It is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Web.

Now the questions

1. it is a good idea to install and run SQL server 2008 R2 Express on this virtual ? Limitations are OK (anyway I have only 1 core and 1GB RAM, 10 GB per DB is perfectly fine), but how about performance ? I dont want it to use all available memory, because the ASP.NET app needs some too because of intensive caching (so maybe few hundreds MBs).
2. Can i set **max server memory** for SQL express to (lets say) 500 MB and expect fair performance? (only 1 small DB - for some time it will be under that 500 MB, and for a long time under 1 GB).
3. Additionally, are there any options i can use to minimize memory footprint/requirements of SQL server express ? (besides NOT installing reporting services, fulltext serach and replication - non of this is needed in my app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.it is a good idea to install and run SQL server 2008 R2 Express on this virtual ?

No. 30gb disc space area laready below what is recommended for windows - ading sql server wont help. On top, you never know how crappy the disc subsystem is, and fast discs are what makes ad atabase fly. DB perforamcne to a large part is controleld by the performance of the disc subsystem and that nromally sucks on virtual discs provided by non specialised hosters.

> 2.Can i set max server memory for SQL express to (lets say) 500 MB and expect fair performance?

Can i load only 100kg on a car and it is suitable= DEPENDS WHAT YOU DO. 500mb for a 10gb database may or may not be enough, depends on usabe patterns.

> 3.Additionally, are there any options i can use to minimize memory footprint/requirements of SQL 
>   server express ?

This is so totalyl not hjow sql server works. Databases want big ram to use it as cache. Minimize it - sure. Then isntead of RAM you bburn IOPS which is a harder resource to get.

I personally think that aproduction server - even a vps - that is so much less powerfull thean a cheap laptop is totally the wrong approach.

Comment: thank you for response. However, you probably didnt noticed important part of my question : there will be 1 small DB - for some time it will be under that 500 MB, and for a long time under 1 GB

Comment: THat may be relevant or not - a small db can still instill thousands of transactions.